# How to display the number of nodes or tags in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I am new to Drupal. I am working on a site that requires me to display the number of nodes (content) in a group/tag. Similar to the way the number of modules and themes currently available for Drupal are shown on the [homepage of Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org).

Can anyone help me on this, or point me to the right module(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to understand that this question is a variation of what the purpose is of one of the [Out-of-the-box examples](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426921) that you get by simply installing (and enabling) the [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, and without any additional configuration.

By doing so, and assuming you have the [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module installed/enabled also, a new view is added to your site. Here are some more details about it, quoted from the linked page above (to which I added some formatting here):

> You can see the charts created via this new view in your own site by
>   navigating to charts/examples or by using a menu link with a title
>   like Charts examples. After doing so, a page is shown with 2 sub-menu
>   tabs:
>
> - the first tab is titled **Built-in examples** (this example is used to
>     showcase [Using the Charts API](https://www.drupal.org/node/233916)).
> - the second tab is titled **Views
>     example**, and is what is created from the new view created during the
>     installation of the charts module. As an alternative to using this
>     tab, just navigate to charts/examples/views in your site. You should
>     then see a column chart and a pie chart, which are followed by a
>     tabular display also. ***Both charts and the table display contain data
>     about the total number of nodes for each of the available content
>     types.***

Since you're new to Drupal, this might be a good starting point to get you going with some of the basic stuff of the Views module. You can use these views to further tune/clone these samples to make them fit your exact needs.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).